# How can I code a textured, no-repeating background for a div from a fixed image when I don't know how tall it will be?

Tags: html, css

I am coding a WordPress theme from a design that has been provided to me. Each post (in the design) is on a background that looks like a piece of paper:

[image: Two blog posts on faux paper]

The issue is that (of course) I don't know how long each blog post will be. I want to slice and dice the image in such a way that it will repeat to fill the blog post div as needed, while still maintaining the look it was designed to have (including the rough edges with transparency, etc.)

I've considered several different ways of accomplishing this, like creating a top, kludged-repeatable middle, and bottom, but everything I've tried is pretty clunky and requires large (filesize) images.

I'm asking here in case there is some technique I should be using but don't know about. I'm having a hard time explaining to Google what I'm looking for, so I'd be grateful for even hints on what keywords to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. There are two options for faking it.

- Create a really long (large) image and assume that no post will go over a certain length.
- Create a top and bottom image "cap" and repeat in the middle. You can make the repeating image large enough that it looks kind of random, but it really isn't.

The real solution is to go back to the designer and tell them this just isn't possible. A real-world solution would be to create a background image that fades to some solid color. That way you can define the background like `background: #000 url('your-image.png') no-repeat center top;` and have the image fade to black (or brown as indicated by your screenshot).

Answer (score 2):

1. Might want to consider [border images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-image) (though apparently no support from IE)
2. Nowadays, you can have multiple background images and/or gradients.  (IE9 does support, but gradient support is all over the place in most browsers; you'd probably have to find a gradient generator like http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ or use css3pie http://css3pie.com/demos/gradient-patterns/ (or both)  Don't forget, because you can have multiple background images, you could create some effect with alpha transparency on your images as well.